# Plot color scale in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

How could I reproduce this color scale in pyplot?

[image: 8-bit-gray-scale]

It is an 8-bit grayscale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With numpy you can create a 8x1 matrix of consecutive values. `plt.imshow()` allows to put that image inside a desired rectangular region. Use `aspect='auto'`to prevent `imshow` to force square pixels, `cmap='Greys'` to get a colormap of grey values and `interpolation='nearest'` so that each 'pixel' gets a flat color (`interpolation='bilinear'` would smooth out the colors).

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = np.linspace(0, 1, 8).reshape((-1, 1))
plt.imshow(img, extent=[110, 370, 5, 240], aspect='auto', cmap='Greys', interpolation='nearest')
plt.xlim(0, 520)
plt.ylim(220, 0)

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Answer (score 1):

I am not reproducing the exact same image, but similar one can be achieved with:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
from pylab import imshow,pcolormesh,show
# ---------------------
nx = 500;ny = 200
ncolors = 8;
dny = int(ny/8);
# ---------------------
A= np.zeros((ny,nx));
for icol in range(ncolors):
    A[(icol-1)*dny:icol*dny,100:400]= (ncolors-icol)*dny
# ----------------------
imshow(A,cmap='Greys');show();
```

You can adjust the real values and locations on your own.

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution I have been shown:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


im1 = np.ones((64,512))
im2 = 2*im1
im3 = 3*im1
im4 = 4*im1
im5 = 5*im1
im6 = 6*im1
im7 = 7*im1
im8 = 8*im1

complete_array = np.concatenate((im1,im2,im3,im4,im5,im6,im7,im8),axis=0)
plt.imshow(complete_array,cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```